# Header in semantic HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-heading

I am designing a semantic mark-up of my HTML page. The page consists of a main content block and of a side bar. There are several independent blocks in the side bar like latest news, links, statistics e.t.c. Each block has a header with a block name: "Statistics", "Links" e.t.c.

The question. Is it a semanticly correct usage of the tag `header` if I put a block name in the `header` tag like `<section id="News"><header>News</header><ul>...</ul></section>`.

Is it a semanticly correct to put the name of the section in `<h*>` tag instead?

What is the difference between the options and why one should use one of the options?

Comment: It's not invalid but it does break the document outline that these new elements are meant to support. See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#outlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using a sectioning element (`section` in your case, but you might want to use `aside`), these sections already have an implicit outline entry.

You can provide an explicit entry by using a heading (`h1`-`h6`).

So yes, you should use a heading element (`h1`-`h6`) for specifying the heading of each block (→ section).

In addition, you *may* use a `header` element. But this is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387534/1591669) (it makes sense to use it if your header consists of more than just the heading).

So I’d go with:

```
<aside>
  <h1>News</h1>
  <!-- content -->
</aside>

<aside>
  <h1>Statistics</h1>
  <!-- content -->
</aside>
```

And for complex headers:

```
<aside>
  <header>
    <h1>News</h1>
    <!-- more header content -->
  </header>
  <!-- content -->
</aside>

<aside>
  <header>
    <h1>Statistics</h1>
    <!-- more header content -->
  </header>
  <!-- content -->
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

that use of a header is valid - that's how sections are meant to be used - see this definition for the use of sections https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941170/3529814

Answer (score 0):

It's completely valid, but if it's just a simple heading, I'd say an `H*` tag will be sufficient and semantically correct on it's own.

If there are several elements describing the section contents, such as a heading, a description and a date tag or something along that path, I would wrap them in a `<header>` tag.