# Which is more semantic for a sidebar of widgets?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

In the following *example* html5 page structure, which of the following is more semantic in respect to the sidebar of widgets (elements which appear in the sidebar are elements which appear on multiple pages and do not necessarily, directly, nor particularly relate to this page of content):

```
<body>
    <header id="site-header">
        ...
    </header>

    <section id="page-body">
        <main>
            <header></header>
            <article></article>
            <footer></footer>
        </main>
        <aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar-a">
            <section id="search-widget">
                ...search field, etc...
            </section>
            <section id="recent-articles-widget">
                ...articles list...
            </section>
        </aside>

        <aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar-b">
            <section id="cloud-tag-widget">
                ...search field, etc...
            </section>
            <section id="recent-articles-widget">
                ...articles list...
            </section>
        </aside>
    </section>
    <footer id="site-footer"> ... </footer>
</body>
```

or...

```
<body>
    <header id="site-header">
        ...
    </header>

    <section id="page-body">
        <main>
            <header></header>
            <article></article>
            <footer></footer>
        </main>
        <section class="sidebar" id="sidebar-a">
            <aside id="search-widget">
                ...search field, etc...
            </aside>
            <aside id="recent-articles-widget">
                ...articles list...
            </aside>
        </section>
        <section class="sidebar" id="sidebar-b">
            <aside id="cloud-tag-widget">
                ...tag list...
            </aside>
            <aside id="popular-articles-widget">
                ...articles list...
            </aside>
        </section>
    </section>
    <footer id="site-footer"> ... </footer>
</body>
```

AKA - Is it more semantic or in any way more appropriate to put multiple asides within a section, or include multiple sections within an aside to create a sidebar of widgets? Should they instead be simple divs within a div? Or divs within a section? Divs within an aside? ***Why?***
Which is easier for screen readers or search engines? ***Why?***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and too broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`aside`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-aside-element) is "tangentially related to the content around" it.

Currently, it doesn’t seem to be defined what "around" means exactly. [Assuming](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20793) that it’s (at least) the content of the parent sectioning content element, then this would mean for your examples:

- `<body> <section> <aside></aside> </section> </body>`
  The `aside` is related to the content of the `section`.
- `<body> <aside> <section></section> </aside> </body>`
  The `aside` is related to the content of the `body` (i.e., of the whole document).

So in your case, you’ll probably want to have `aside` as descendant of `body` (and of no other sectioning content element).

The next thing to decide would be: one `aside` with several sub-sections vs. several `aside`. I’d go with a [separate `aside`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23048210/1591669) for each "sidebar block", unless you can logically group (*) these blocks.

* I.e., if there is a natural heading that could be used (it doesn’t matter if you actually use it) to group several sidebar blocks, use one `aside` with `section` childs for these.

Answer (score 0):

The `<aside>` tag defines some content aside from the content it is placed in.

The aside content should be related to the surrounding content.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I know what the aside tag is. As well as the section, header, footer, nav, and all other tags in the HTML5 spec. What I'm asking is: what is the most appropriate or effective way of using it in a sidebar context?