# Right usage of the <header> tag in HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have read that the  tag is the header of a section. It could be used more then 1 time in the document.

Should I use the `<header>` tag in the section:

```
<section>
<header>
</header>
</section>
```

or above the `<section>` like:

```
<header>
</header>
<section>
</section>
```

Is it possible to have this sctucture for heading information and the sections:

```
<section id="main">

    <header id="results">
      <h1>My Results</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="results">
        <section id="result1">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           <div class="body"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="result2">
           <h2>Title</h2>
           <div class="body"></div>
        </section>
       .
       .
       .
    </section>

</section>
```

do you thing this example is a good one for semantic usage oh the HTML5 tags header and section?

Or should I use instead of the `<section id="main">` , the `<main>` tag?

Comment: You should use `header` inside of `section` and using `sections` like `<section id="...">` is a better practice. Check **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags)** for some good explanations.

Comment: `main` tag should be used only once, globally, as the container of main content of your site, in your example, obviously, you should change `<section id="main">` to `<main>`. Web crawlers often look only into the `main` tag if it exists, what prevents you from, for example, caching navigation bar when you have a poor content in your site, for example, on index site, and so on. `div`, on the other hand, should be used only when no other tag passses to the semantic of it`s content.

Comment: It seems that your second question about `main` has no relation to your first question about `header`. You should create a separate question in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Your two cases have a different meaning:

Here the `section` has a `header`:

```
<section>
<header>
</header>
</section>
```

Here the parent *section* (*) has a `header` and a child `section` (which has no `header`):

```
<header>
</header>
<section>
</section>
```

(* Could be a sectioning element like `article`/`section`/`nav`/`aside`, or a sectioning root like `body`/etc.)

Both cases are possible, it depends on the meaning of your content.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387534/1591669) to a related question, which contains an example document with different `header` elements.

Comment: thanks man. I have understand now the header function. I have here an example structure of my site. Can you verify it please? The problem is, where can I post it, because it is not allowed to answer my question :-(

Comment: @NikoNik: If you have a specific question/problem, create a new question here on Stack Overflow. If you want a review of your code, post a question on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use section as a wrapper for styling.
  correct way is

```
<body>
    <header>        
            <h1>Header in h1</h1>
            <h2>Subheader in h2</h2>        
    </header>    
    <section>
        <article>
            <header>
                <h1>Article #1</h1>
            </header>
            <section>
                This is the first article.
            </section>
        </article>
        <article>
            <header>
                <h1>Article #2</h1>
            </header>
            <section>
                This is the second article.  
            </section>
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <section>
            <h1>Links</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>        
    </aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

About section and header click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags) and for html5 possible mistakes 
[here](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/)

Your html should be

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Search Form</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
       <h1>Search Result Title</h1>
       <ul id="sponsored_ads">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
       </ul>
       <ul id="organic_ads">
        <li></li>
           <li></li>
      </ul>        
       <article id="left_menu_1">
         <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
         </ul>
       </article>
       <article id="left_menu_2>
         <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
         </ul>
       </article>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm but where are the HTML5 tags in your example?

Comment: Its just an example. For complete information links are provided for the same.

Comment: But I have it in this way now. I would like to use now the semantic tags instead. How to do this?

Comment: edited the example using semantic tags. You can now change your html accordingly.