# What is AppBar vs ToolBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-components

All the material-ui examples show Toolbar inside Appbar. Why not just Appbar? What's the difference between the two?

https://material.io/design/components/ does *not* have Toolbar component, only "App bars: top".

https://material.io/develop/web/components/toolbar/ says "The existing MDCToolbar component and styles will be removed in a future release"

So will material-ui Toolbar go away eventually?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I was looking at the default CSS properties produced by each component. The main purpose of **Toolbar** is to display its children with an inline display (elements are placed next to each other), something **Appbar** doesn't do. The **AppBar** component uses *display: flex* and *flex-direction: column*, that means direct descendants are stacked on top of each other. On the other hand **Toolbar** uses *display: flex* too, but doesn't set *flex-direction*, which means it uses its default value: *row*. That being said, the **Button** component uses *display: inline-block*. That is the reason why elements are placed next to each other inside **Toolbar** components.

Let say, for example, we have an **Appbar** with a **Toolbar** with two **Button**s as children:

```
<AppBar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="inherit" >
            Button 1
        </Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="inherit">
            Button 2
        </Button>
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

The result of this code is:

[image: here]

But, if we remove the **Toolbar** and place the **Button**s directly under the **AppBar** component:

```
<AppBar>
    <Button variant="outlined" color="inherit" >
        Button 1
    </Button>
    <Button variant="outlined" color="inherit">
        Button 2
    </Button>
</AppBar>
```

the result will be very different as shown below, because now the buttons are direct descendants of the **AppBar** component and so, they will be stacked on top of each other.

[image: here]

As you see, **AppBar** and **Toolbar** have different purposes. Thats why I think **Toolbar** will never go away.

Comment: I understand the difference in CSS. but what are the different purposes?

Comment: @Chiptus Did you ever find out the actual difference?

Comment: @PrivateOmega actually no, I just understood they are needed together

Comment: I'd like to add that AppBar should probably only be used [once per page/section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837269/html5-using-header-or-footer-tag-twice) as it creates a header element. [Sectioning elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/HTML5.html) include aside, footer, form, header, main, nav and section. This adds semantic value for the likes of screen readers and other accessibility tools. Toolbar does not create this element.

Answer (score 26):

The **AppBar** is used to structure your document. You put in content what you would normally place inside a  tag e.g the title of your page and navigation links. If you examine your page by pressing F12 you will notice the AppBar created a `<header>` tag.
-> So the AppBar is used to give your page a place to put in introductional and navigational content

[image]

You can visualize the **Toolbar** as a real life tool belt. In the virtual world instead of tools we place icons and buttons on it. You can also add your brand name inside the tool bar just like manufacturers do that on their belts.
-> The toolbar is a wrapper where you can place elements in a horizontal line.

AppBar can be used without a Toolbar and a Toolbar doesn't have to be placed inside a AppBar. If you want your header to look like a toolbar it makes sense to do `<AppBar><Toolbar>...</Toolbar></AppBar>`. If you want a bar at the center of the page just to show off icons a Toolbar without a AppBar would make sense.