# Why do we always have a ToolBar inside an AppBar in Material UI. Can we avoid one or the other?

Tags: material-ui

Why do we always have a ToolBar inside an AppBar in Material UI. Can we avoid one or the other? Are there principles surround each one?
can we just have

```
<Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
  <div className={classes.container}>
    <CardMedia
      className={classes.media}
      image={logo}
      title="Logo"
    />
  </div>
  <Button className={classes.containerMenu} color="inherit">
    <MenuIcon className={classes.iconButton}/>
    Menu
  </Button>
</Toolbar>
```

and avoid the surrounding `<AppBar>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653103/what-is-appbar-vs-toolbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is AppBar vs ToolBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653103/what-is-appbar-vs-toolbar)