# Is it valid to use multiple footer (or header) elements as adjacent siblings?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am working with an eBook. For the Copyright page, the Details page containing general information about the book and other publication notes I am using the `footer` element.

Now, I have two basic options. One of them is using a single `footer` element containing multiple `section` elements to accommodate all of the pages (4 in total). The other option is to have multiple `footer` elements, each containing the specific pages.

The first option (only one `footer` with multiple `section`) seems better to me, except that when I validate the HTML, it says that I need to have heading (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) for each of the `section` elements. The problem with this is that I do not want to have to use headings for these secondary sections, since they are not as important as the main content of the book and yet, these headings will be prominent and be placed on top of the page outline, making them appear more important than they are.

Can I have multiple `footer` elements that are adjacent siblings from each other? Is this semantically valid?

The other question/answer that I could find related to this one was [html5: using header or footer tag twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4837269/6885008), but it just discusses the use of multiple `footer` within a page, but not necessarily having them next to each other as adjacent siblings (multiple `footer` for the *same* section).

Comment: There is nothing in the recommendation that prohibits multiple sibling `footer` elements. You just can't have nested `footer`s.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree. I voted to close the question as opinion based because it's asking for opinions on whether doing that is okay. My comment does not say whether it's okay, just that the recommendation doesn't prohibit anything.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Whether something is valid HTML isn't a matter of opinion; it's defined by a spec and there are even validators by the spec-writing authority where you can test your HTML for validity.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 standard specifies that nested `footer` elements are not permitted. *Adjacent* would not be *nested* though. Adjacent would mean multiple `footer` elements for a single parent element, or side-by-side footers which seems sloppy. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer).

It really boils down to keeping it simple. Ask yourself, what is the use case for adjacent or side-by-side, or double, `footer` elements?